# Why Foundation doesn't provide foundation.scss when we setup project with compass?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I was trying to setup new project with Compass but after setup I found that in sass folder foundation.scss was not there. So I had to put it there manually and also had to change path of stylesheets/app.css to sass/app.css ... after that it was working fine... my question is that why i need to make these changes when I am doing everything according to documentation? (I am  using foundation4 with sass).

Comment: Why would there be a foundation.scss anywhere?

Comment: Because it includes grid, global and other necessary foundation components. and command prompt show you an error because of this missing file.

Comment: Then you didn't follow the directions correctly.  Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388506/how-do-the-sass-variables-get-assigned-to-css-selectors-with-foundation-4