# Importing a .scss(sass) file from another directory?

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

- source_dir

  - scss

    - styles.scss
  - bootstrap-scss

    - _variables.scss
    - bootstrap.scss

So I am thinking I might just move **all** the bootstrap.scss files into the main "scss" folder, but thats more a last resort.

My problem is I am trying to import the "_variables.scss" similar to how "bootstrap.scss" does so I can set variables that will effect my main bootstrap.css and my written styles.css with one variable, cool huh? But when I try to import it in `source_dir > scss > styles.scss` I get an error.

```
// Failed
@import "variables";

// Failed
@import "../bootstrap-scss/variables";
```

Now lastly, I am using gulp to compile so I don't really want to watch the files, that was the chosen answer here [SASS: Import a file from a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502313/sass-import-a-file-from-a-different-directory) I need to read some more on that post, but there has to be a good way to import these days?

Comment: I understand you'd like to keep Boostrap away from your codebase; have you tried to create a symbolic link to `bootstrap` somewhere in `scss`?

Comment: Either way, the `-I` suggestion from linked question should still be useful to you- you'd just need to somehow tell Gulp to pass this flag during compilation.

Comment: I need to google that, I am entering brand new territory. But no I have not tried it.

Comment: If you really want to keep Bootstrap out of your source tree, I recommend using it as a Compass extension instead.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I've been looking for reasons to use compass, yet to use it thus far but now seems appropriate, and there is of course a gulp plugin for that. So compass will allow me to import variables, seems like I would have to dig to get that deep, any useful tips?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388506/how-do-the-sass-variables-get-assigned-to-css-selectors-with-foundation-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949004/sass-or-less-packaging

Comment: @cimmanon see that they are using require do I use require like they do here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry The require is done within config.rb (this is a file generated by Compass that contains your configuration -- things that are typically set via command line flags when using Sass).

Answer (score 2):

I've tried out the symbolic link approach I suggested in a comment earlier, and it seems to work. Here's an example folder structure:

```
.
├── sources
│   └── sass
│       ├── bootstrap -> ../../vendor/bootstrap
│       └── style.scss
└── vendor
    └── bootstrap
        └── _variables.scss
```

in style.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables"
```

I've created the (relative) symbolic link with `ln -s ../../vendor/bootstrap sources/sass/` and Sass picks up the location correctly.

Comment: Okay awesome, you say its working let me give it a crack, first I need to actually google symbolic link approach, ill brb.

Comment: Can you give me a tip on symbolic link approach I am not getting it, on information overload.

Comment: Do I just invoke `ln -s ../../vendor/bootstrap sources/sass/` in the command line, and that creates the symbolic link? Maybe I need to be inside the sass dir?

Comment: The first arg after `-s` is the target path to point to (relative to symlink file location - it's not being resolved at this point), and the second is where to create the link itself.

Comment: I implemented this `@import "../../../../../../../../../../source/scss-bootstrap/variables";` and it works, obviously ugly, I am going to try your method now.