# How is this bootstrap scss file finding the imports?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm integrating bootstrap into my django project, and I've roughly followed the instructions [here](http://www.lasolution.be/blog/using-your-own-flavor-bootstrap-django-project-part-1.html) to get the SASS version working.

I'm trying to understand what's going on though, and one thing confuses me. This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
myapp
    ...
    sass
        bootstrapped
            _bootstrap_variables.scss
            bootstrap_compiled.scss
    static
        bootstrap-sass-3.2.0
            (All the stuff downloaded from bootstrap's website)
        css
            bootstrapped
                bootstrap_compiled.css
    config.rb
```

My bootstrap_compiled.scss file is just:

```
@import "bootstrap-compass";
@import "bootstrap-variables";
@import "bootstrap";
```

And in the test template, I'm doing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrapped/bootstrap_compiled.css' %}" />
```

But in bootstrap_compiled.scss, bootstrap.scss and _bootstrap-compass.scss are actually in the bootstrap-sass-3.2.0 folder. In config.rb, I have this line:

```
sass_dir = "sass"
```

I'm confused as to how the bootstrap_compiled.scss file can find the second and third files and compile everything correctly.

Also, am I supposed to keep the bootstrap-sass-3.2.0 folder in static/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the Sass variables get assigned to CSS selectors with Foundation 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388506/how-do-the-sass-variables-get-assigned-to-css-selectors-with-foundation-4)